# Quisiera ver un valor de un decimal sin que se redondee C++

Tags: c++, redondeo

Necesito ayuda con un código en C++, el ejercicio me pide que haga un cálculo, si el resultado es, por ejemplo 1.57, en la salida debe mostrar 1.5, (la variable puede ser float o double) sin que se haga el redondeamiento.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int c=0;
cin >> c;
while(c--){
    int Vkh=0;
    double Vms=0, Vm=0;
    cin >> Vkh;
    Vms=Vkh/3.6;
    Vm=Vms/340;
    printf(" %.1f\n", Vm);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y el código? ...

Comment: Sorry, ya lo coloqué

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La librería `cmath` (`math.h` para los que vienen de C), tiene una función `trunc` que permite truncar un `float` o un `double`. La función de truncado elimina la parte decimal del número. Para eliminar un número determinado de decimales se puede optar por incluir temporalmente esos decimales en la parte entera del número, aplicar truncado y volver a colocarlos como decimales:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  float numero = 1.57;
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::trunc(numero*10)/10;
}
```

Ejemplo en [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/a5OMnfErW7xUnoXe)

Esto se puede dejar más *bonito* si dividimos el código en funciones:

```
constexpr double Exp(int numero)
{
  return ( numero <= 0 )? 1 : 10 * Exp(numero-1);
}

double Truncar(double numero, int decimales)
{
  return std::trunc(numero*Exp(decimales))/Exp(decimales);
}

void ImprimirDouble(double numero, int decimales)
{
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(decimales) << Truncar(numero,decimales) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  double numero = 3.777;
  ImprimirDouble(numero,0);
  ImprimirDouble(numero,1);
  ImprimirDouble(numero,2);
}
```

Ejemplo en [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O7GE54Eo6vWDos2z)

Aunque a mi personalmente me gusta más la opción de darle un tipado fuerte a la variable... queda el código más limpio. El ejemplo se puede abstraer con plantillas y demás, pero creo que con ello se perdería el foco de lo que intento enseñar:

```
namespace MathUtils
{

constexpr double Exp(int numero)
{
  return ( numero <= 0 )? 1 : 10 * Exp(numero-1);
}

double Truncar(double numero, int decimales)
{
  return std::trunc(numero*Exp(decimales))/Exp(decimales);
}

}

class Double
{
  double value;

public:

  explicit Double(double value)
    : value(value)
  { }

  operator double() const
  { return value; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Double const& value);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Double const& value)
{
    auto precision = os.precision();
    return os << std::fixed << MathUtils::Truncar(value,precision);
}

int main()
{
  Double numero(3.777);
  std::cout << std::setprecision(0) << numero << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << numero << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << numero << '\n';
}
```

Ejemplo en [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I5qyE6XjQKpqWUi9)

Esta solución presenta varias ventajas:

- La salida a la consola o fichero es más natural.
- Tener un tipado fuerte evita conversiones no deseadas.
- El código es bastante más expresivo. Quizás no se aprecie en este ejemplo pero a una escala mayor se ve con rapidez.

Answer (score 3):

Esta es una forma simple y rapida, no estoy orgulloso de ella, debe haber una mejor ... :-(

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  printf("%f\n", 3.0/7);
  printf("%.4f\n", 3.0/7);
  printf("%.4f\n", (float)((int)(3.0/7*10000))/10000);
  return 0;
}
```

#### Salida

```
$ g++ stack.cpp && ./a.out
0.428571
0.4286
0.4285
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: De todas formas espera, deben venir respuestas mejores, espero ...